# Scan QR code using front camera react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, qr-code

I tried using this module: https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner,
But this works for only back camera. I need to implement from front camera instead.

Though, they are supporting front camera but that does not scan and they provided the reason here:
https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner/issues/128

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/2363#issuecomment-509765993

So I am looking out for some alternate to this one.

Comment: Hey, I am not completely remember if this library supports different cameras but at least you may try https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/

Comment: @Kison Thanks for a quick response but my code is pure react native code. its not. built in Expo.

Comment: I understand, I assume you may try to use it without expo